# Rejoining an ex-employer

Tags: new-job, employer-relations, career-switch

I am planning to make a switch in my industry i.e. IT industry.

If I opt to join the same company from where I had resigned earlier instead of joining a new one, will it make me look desperate or needy? will there be any negative impact of this decision?

Answer (score 10):

No, there will be no negative impact, unless you create one.

However, before you take the decision, make sure of one thing: the reason for which you left the organization earlier, is not present currently (to the best of your ability to foresee). If you think that problem (or side effects) are not relevant to the (re)new engagement - by all means, feel free to go ahead and accept the offer.

You applied for an open position, like many others, and got selected in the process. I've known many people who left and joined back the same organization multiple times - they are considered professionals - nothing more, nothing less.

This is also one of reasons why "burning the bridges" (when you leave) is considered a bad idea. Given the chance and situation, you may want to work for any previous employer, so maintaining a good professional relationship is always welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Usually there is no problem in working again for a previous employer, as long as it is good for you.

For example, I was in a company where I had stagnated, where I was the unofficial leader of the team but was trying to make it official. Since that would involve payment raise, I was having trouble achieving it.

I then received an invitation to join another company as a team leader and accepted. However, the job was not what I was told it would be, and I started having to do a lot of overtime. For the first 9 weeks in this new job, I had no weekend, for example.

Failing to solve that issue internally, I started looking for a new job five months later. My previous employer discovered and called me to talk and offered me the leadership of my previous team.

Then I returned and stayed there for 3 years, and it was good for both parties.

So, short answer, if it will be good for you, and you know why you are choosing it over the tech giant, go for it. If, however, you are a little concerned of going to a new place and would feel more comfortable going to an already known place, maybe you should reflect more before deciding.

good luck :-)